# Check if string have specific number of symbols

Tags: php, regex

In trying to figure out how to do it with preg_match, but I'm left with no clue.
So what I'm trying is

```
$string = 'abc.hello.world.123.hola';

if ($string have 3 or more ".") {
    echo 'true';
}
```

Comment: You could attempt to match the regular expression `\.(?:[^.]*\.)*2`. That will match if and only if the string contains at least three periods. To match exactly four periods: `^[^.]*(?:\.[^.]*)*4\$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you said `preg_match`, but there is a specific PHP function for this. Use `substr_count()` :)

```
$string = 'abc.hello.world.123.hola';
$dots = substr_count($string, '.');

echo $dots; // output: 4
if ($dots >= 3) {
  // do something
}
```